# Raspberry Pi power supply

Tags: power-supply, alternative-power

This has been asked and answered many times, but my specific question is not in the list of results when I search.

I have a nominal 2.6A supply here, and it remains stable at 5V up to exactly this amp load with no voltage drop. It’s quality. So I would just like to know if I need to do some resistor magic/short-circuit on the TX/RX lines for it to work *perfectly* with my pi3.

I’ve observed on most quality 5V supplies that RX/TX are shorted, and I am aware of apple’s weird voltage divider circus on their iPhone/iPad PSUs - but this is a Pi - does it even pay attention to RX/TX signal lines?

My expected max load is 1.5-2A, not more. I’ll pull an extra 5V rail from this PSU for something else nearby.

Let me know if I need to clarify.

Note:
I’ve used a 2.1A iPad charger up to now, and it does not work well at all. Even when I observe a load of only 1.3A, there are not-enough-power  indicators when I attach 50mA USB peripherals. A standard off the shelf charger at 2A has no issues... But I need the extra 5V rail for something else nearby.

**TL;DR:**
I am connecting 5V/GND to a male microUSB breakout board, and need to know if using resistors or shorting the data lines (the aforementioned RX/TX) will in any way affect the Pi’s operation. If so, how?

Update: The PSU wasn’t the issue; I was using too thin, too long a cable. At the Pi I measured 5.10V when it was turned off, but ~4.85V when on and loaded. So I should read 5.25V at the Pi when it’s off:/

Comment: Could you explain what the RX/TX lines are?  I can make no sense of the question.  I can't see any relevance to the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Receive and transmission lines in a standard USB1.1/2 cable. I’m connecting the 5V/GND to the 5V/GND pins on a little male microUSB breakout board, and am curious to know if the RX/TX pins are relevant. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/123172/what-is-the-ideal-way-to-handle-data-pins-d-and-d-on-a-usb-power-adapter-to-be . I would have asked on EE.SE, but they’d obviously say this question belongs here.

Comment: For posterity: A value of 0-200 ohms between the data pins on USB1/USB2 informs a device that this power source conforms to the DCP section of USB Battery Charging Specification, i.e. a source capable of providing <= 1.5A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pi's microUSB power socket is only connected to pins 1 (5V) and 5 (ground).  Pins 2, 3, and 4 are not connected.

Schematics at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/README.md